# Using max() and min() unsuccessfully in Python array

Tags: python, sorting, max, min

**Context**: Continuing with my self-learn of Python, I recently completed a textbook exercise that asked for a program that allowed the user to define 'x' number of years and to be able to input, for every month in 'x', a value for rainfall.

**Issue:** Below is my code, which works 'ok', however the latest exercise demands I 'expand' my code to present the numerically largest and smallest user input rainfall value, in a print statement.

**Disclosure: I have looked on S.O to try finding the solution to my question, but nothing seems to be close enough to my challenge, to help me.**

**What I've tried:** I have tried using `max()` and `min()` however I keep getting a `TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable` when I type the code `print(max(monthlyRainfall)` or `print(min(monthlyRainfall)`

```
def yearsToTrack():
    userYearsTracking = int(input("How many years do you want to track: "))
    return userYearsTracking

def calculationAlgorithm(userYearsTracking):
    totalMonths = 0
    totalRainfall = 0
    for currentYear in range (1, userYearsTracking +1):
        for currentMonth in range (1, 13):
            monthlyRainfall = int(input("Inches of rainfall for month " + format(currentMonth, "d",) + " | year " +
                                    format(currentYear, "d",)+": "))
            totalMonths += 1
            totalRainfall += monthlyRainfall
    averageRainfall = totalRainfall / totalMonths
    print("Total months: " + str(totalMonths))
    print("Total rain:", format(totalRainfall), "(inch)")
    print("Total average rainfall:", round(averageRainfall,2), "(inch)")

def main():
    userYearsTracking = yearsToTrack()
    calculationAlgorithm(userYearsTracking)
main()
```

Is anyone able to offer some 'pointers' as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: `print(str(...))`

Comment: Can you mention your current output

Comment: Sounds like you're passing an `int` to `max`/`min` instead of a list of them.

Comment: Those functions (min, max) are called on iterables (lists, tuples, etc.). There is no such data structure in your code, you just maintain totals.

Comment: You need to add something like `overallMin = min(overallMin, monthlyRainfall)` to your inner loop. Same for max. These should be initialized like the sum variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's built-in min() and max() functions expect iterable object like **list, set**, etc. I think you are putting only one integer which is not so correct (how can you pick min or max number when only 1 number given - obviously it is bot min and max).
One way of doing this would be:

1. declare list var:

   `rainfallList = []`
2. Then when you get monthlyRainfall, you should add this code:

   `rainfallList.append(monthlyRainfall)`
3. After all for loops you can use **min(rainfallList)** and/or **max(rainfallList)**

So your final code should be:

```
def yearsToTrack():
    userYearsTracking = int(input("How many years do you want to track: "))
    return userYearsTracking

def calculationAlgorithm(userYearsTracking):
    totalMonths = 0
    totalRainfall = 0

    rainfallList = []

    for currentYear in range (1, userYearsTracking +1):
        for currentMonth in range (1, 13):
            monthlyRainfall = int(input("Inches of rainfall for month " + format(currentMonth, "d",) + " | year " +
                                    format(currentYear, "d",)+": "))
            totalMonths += 1
            rainfallList.append(monthlyRainfall)

            totalRainfall += monthlyRainfall
    averageRainfall = totalRainfall / totalMonths
    print("Total months: " + str(totalMonths))
    print("Total rain:", format(totalRainfall), "(inch)")
    print("Total average rainfall:", round(averageRainfall,2), "(inch)")
    print("Min rain:", format(min(rainfallList)), "(inch)")
    print("Max rain:", format(max(rainfallList)), "(inch)")

def main():
    userYearsTracking = yearsToTrack()
    calculationAlgorithm(userYearsTracking)
main()
```

Comment: Thank you for the simplicity of explanation, it really helped. I have thought about the declaring a list, but kept persuading myself I didn't need to.

Comment: I am happy that it was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`sys.maxsize`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.maxsize) and `0` to intilize variables for tracking the minimum and maximum rainfall values that realistically the user will never enter above above or below respectively.

However for the second case just to make sure you can also add a simple check to ensure the user does not enter a negative rainfall amount:

```
def calculationAlgorithm(userYearsTracking):
    totalMonths = 0
    totalRainfall = 0
    maxRainfall = 0
    minRainfall = sys.maxsize
    for currentYear in range (1, userYearsTracking +1):
        for currentMonth in range (1, 13):
            monthlyRainfall = int(input("Inches of rainfall for month " + format(currentMonth, "d",) + " | year " +
                                    format(currentYear, "d",)+": "))
            if monthlyRainfall < 0:
                print("Error invalid rainfall entered")
                sys.exit()
            if monthlyRainfall > maxRainfall:
                maxRainfall = monthlyRainfall
            if monthlyRainfall < minRainfall:
                minRainfall = monthlyRainfall
            totalMonths += 1
            totalRainfall += monthlyRainfall
    averageRainfall = totalRainfall / totalMonths
    print("Total months: " + str(totalMonths))
    print("Total rain:", format(totalRainfall), "(inch)")
    print("Total average rainfall:", round(averageRainfall,2), "(inch)")
    print("Largest input rainfall: " + str(maxRainfall))
    print("Smallest input rainfall: " + str(minRainfall))
```

Try out the full program with above changes **[here.](https://repl.it/repls/VerifiableTomatoLoris)**

**Example Usage:**

```
How many years do you want to track:  1
Inches of rainfall for month 1 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 2 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 3 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 4 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 5 | year 1:  4
Inches of rainfall for month 6 | year 1:  1
Inches of rainfall for month 7 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 8 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 9 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 10 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 11 | year 1:  2
Inches of rainfall for month 12 | year 1:  2
Total months: 12
Total rain: 25 (inch)
Total average rainfall: 2.08 (inch)
Largest input rainfall: 4
Smallest input rainfall: 1
```

**N.B.** I have only used **[camelCase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)** in naming the new variables as that is the style you are using. I would recommend changing all the names of the variables in your program to [**snake_case**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) as that is the convention in python.